# Esperi, ke kaj u-verboj

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, grammar

Ŝajnas al mi, ke plejofte homoj uzas la u-modon por ĉi tiaj frazoj:

> Mi volas, ke ni iru

> Mi petas, ke vi helpu min

Kaj mi ŝatas ĉi tiun uzon. Tamen, mi konfuziĝas pri kiam oni ***devas*** uzas la u-modon. Ekzemple, kun "esperi"

> Mi esperas, ke vi amuziĝos/u

Eble en kelkaj kuntekstoj, "Mi esperas, ke (substantivo) (u-verbo)" estus la plej bona, sed jen kelkaj frazoj en kiuj alia finajxo sxajnas pli bona:

> Mi esperas, ke vi havos bonan nokton cxe la festo! (-os, cxar mi esperas, ke cxe la festo, estos bona por vi, en la estonteco. Eble oni povus diri "-u", sed mi volas esprimi la ne-jam-okazecon de la ago per -os)

> Mi esperas, ke vi havas bonan tagon! (-as, cxar mi esperas, ke la tago nun estas bona por vi)

> Mi esperas, ke vi amuzigxis dum la semajnfino! (-is, cxar mi esperas, ke dum la semajnfino, vi amuzigxis. Mi volas esprimi la pastintecon de la ago, cxar la semajnfino jam pasis)

Eble en cxiuj tiuj kuntekstoj, la -u finajxo funkcius, sed gxi ne sxajnas esti la plej bona.

Mi do scivolas, cxu oni ***devas*** uzi la -u finajxon cxiam kun ke-frazoj? Cxu, se mi volas, mi povas uzi alian finajxon? Sxajnas ke eble ne, cxar laux [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/vola.html):

> U-modo estas uzata en ke-frazoj, se la ĉeffrazo iel montras volon, celon, opinion k.s.

Kaj esperi sxajnas montri volon. Tamen, ial mi dauxre pensas ke eble kun "esperi" estas malsame. Cxu cxi tio estas nur eble antauxkredo pro mia denaska lingvo (la anlga) kaj mi nur forgesu gxin kaj cxiam uzu la -u finajxon kun esperi? Aux cxu ne uzi la -u finajxon en cxi tiuj kuntekstoj estas en ordo?

Comment: Laŭ mi "Mi pensas, ke ĝi estu bona" estas malĝusta frazo.

Comment: Tio estas bona ideo, sed mi pensas ke gxi povus esti en gxusta. "Mi pensas, ke gxi estu bona" signifas "I think, that it should be good". Tamen, vi pravas, ke kvankam gxi gxustas, gxi ne vere rilatas al mia demando eble. Mi redaktos kaj aldonos alian ekzemplon :-)

Comment: Cxu "Mi petas, ke vi helpu min" estas pli bona ekzemplo laux vi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Laŭ Reta Vortaro](https://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-1g.html#esper.0i):
Kredi, ke tio, kion oni deziras, realiĝos:

[Laŭ PIV](https://vortaro.net/#esperi_kd): Atendi kun fido la realiĝon de tio, kion oni deziras

Oni ne povas uzi plurajn modojn verbajn samtempe. Tio signifas ke bezonatas elekti unu el ili (-us, -as, -os, -is, -u).

En ke-frazo kiu sekvas `voli`, `peti`, `deziri`,... oni kutime elektas la -u formon, ĉar volo estas ĉefa trajto.

En ke-frazo kiu sekvas `esperi` oni kutime elektas la -os formon, ĉar `esperi` rilatas atendon aŭ kredon je nepre estonta okazo de io. Oni *povus* tamen emfazi la nuancon de volo per la -u formo.

El [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/ke/verboformoj.html#i-ppj):

> Mi esperas ke vi plenumos mian peton kiel eble plej baldaŭ.OV.487 ≈ Mi
> atendas kun fido, ke vi efektive plenumos mian peton...
>
> Normale oni
> uzu la realan modon post esperi, sed oni povus eble uzi U-modon, se
> oni volas aldoni nuancon de volo: Mi esperas, ke vi venu. = Mi esperas
> kaj volas, ke vi venu.

Comment: Nur por certigxi, vi pensas ke uzi ankaux -is kaj -as estas bona, cxu ne? Kiel en "Mi esperas, ke vi amuzigxis dum la semajnfino!"? La esperata amuzigxo jam estus okazinta, sed la *atendo* aux *kredo* estas pri **cxu** la amuzigxo ja okazis, do laux mi cxi tiu uzo estas gxusta kaj bona kiel kun -os.  Vi samopinias, cxu ne?

Comment: En tiu frazo mi pensas ke vi atendas kion la alia diros, kaj tio ja estas estonteca. La objekto de la espero estas tiu konfirmo. La subkomprenata frazo estas miaopinie: "mi esperas ke [vi diros ke] vi amuziĝis semajnfine".

Comment: Interese, jes! Dankon! Aux eble ankaux "Mi esperas, [ke mi ekscios], ke vi amuzigxis semajnfine". Bona ideo! :-)